# Render GameObject only when they are near to the controller/camera

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, rendering

Me and my friends are trying to develop a game on the android and we are trying our best to reduce the lag.

Is it possible to render objects only when they are near to the controller?

We have this island so it has a lot of trees in the scene.

We are still pretty new to Unity. If it is possible, how? Thanks.

Comment: It is totally inconceivable you will have to worry about performance.  it is absolutely a non-issue.  Note that Unity *completely automatically* culls everything for you.

Comment: Although what you say is true, we still get an fps at around 20-40 while ingame. Im testing it on a Z3 compact.

Comment: wait - trees ??  surely you are using **Unity's terrain system** - right?  It's incredibly efficient.  Essentially, you "can't make your own trees"!?!?   Are you making trees manually ?!

Comment: pls include a screenshot, it's impossible to help otherwise

Comment: your trees are billboards right?

Comment: I am so very sorry for the late response. Me and my team are doing our own trees, and only low poly. We were told to do low poly 3D objects, so we did. Here's a screenshot of our game. [link](http://imgur.com/2uNusNs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do rthis in two ways.

**1**. Unity's built in **Level of Detail** (LOD) is the first solution you should go for.Create multiple 3D models for those GameObject. High detailed object, mid detail, low detailed and really really row detailed polygon.

When you are far from that object, Unity would only show the low detailed 3D model. As soon as you move closer to the object, Unity would automatically swap the 3D model with a high detailed 3D Model. This improves the memory and the speed of the game. To see how to set this up Google "Level of Detail unity" and watch the videos or follow Unity [tutorial](http://docs.unity3d.com/400/Documentation/Manual/LevelOfDetail.html). It requires visual to understand

**2**. Another solution is to check the distance between the camera and the GameObject you want to hide with `Vector3.Distance`, then hide it by disable the `Renderer` by making`Renderer.enabled` to `false`.

Below is a complete working code for this method. Just attach the code below to **each** of the trees or mesh you want to hide when far away from the camera.
You can adjust the `distanceToAppear` variable to fit your needs.

```
public class MeshMonitor : MonoBehaviour
{
    Transform mainCamTransform; // Stores the FPS camera transform
    private bool visible = true;
    public float distanceToAppear = 8;
    Renderer objRenderer;

    private void Start()
    {
        mainCamTransform = Camera.main.transform;//Get camera transform reference
        objRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>(); //Get render reference
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        disappearChecker();
    }
    private void disappearChecker()
    {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(mainCamTransform.position, transform.position);

        // We have reached the distance to Enable Object
        if (distance < distanceToAppear)
        {
            if (!visible)
            {
                objRenderer.enabled = true; // Show Object
                visible = true;
                Debug.Log("Visible");
            }
        }
        else if (visible)
        {
            objRenderer.enabled = false; // Hide Object
            visible = false;
            Debug.Log("InVisible");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I've been thinking of doing and I just can't implement it in unity. Thank you so much!

Comment: hold it dude - are you including your OWN "manual" trees ?!!  like real physical trees?

Comment: All Cameras in unity have two "Clipping Plane" distance values: far, and near.
The camera will only renders objects, or parts of objects, that have a distance from the camera, within this range.  Why did't you use that, programmer?

Comment: @JoeBlow I was thinking of putting them one by one. LOL. Sorry im not that active, I keep forgetting on checking this. And, Unity's built in tree system? Is that the one in the Terrain? Im really kinda new to this.

Comment: hi @carlolol  Sure, in Terrain.  I really suggest you spend some time with the Terrain system, just give it a go.  I believe you have totally wasted your time "making trees" when all you do in Unity is click a button and it does all the trees.

Comment: @JoeBlow we actually did made use of it. Because Programmer said something about the distance to the Player to the object, I thought of putting trees one by one.